# Why can't I return my object as its' interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a series of interface definitions, all of which compile (so my objects are composed correctly).  The objects instantiate, as expected.  However, when I try to return the object from its' underlying factory I get the following error:

**ERROR:**

> *Unable to cast object of type
>   'SampleLibrary.Domain.DataAcessors.Person.SQLDataAccessor' to type
>   'Common.Contracts.DataAccessors.IDataAccessorModel`2[SampleLibrary.Contracts.Models.IPerson,SampleLibrary.Domain.DataAccessors.Types.SqlServer]'.*

Please keep in mind I am trying to return each instance as the IDataAccessor interface.

**CODE:**

```
public interface IDataAccessor<I, T>
{
    T AccessType { get; }
}

public interface IDataAccessorModel<I, T> : IDataAccessor<I, T>
{
    I Instance { get; }

    IResult<string> Get(I instance);
    IResult<string> Add(I instance);
    IResult<string> Update(I instance);
    IResult<string> Delete(I instance);
}

public class SQLDataAccessor : IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, IAccessType>
{
    internal SQLDataAccessor(IResult<string> result)
    {
        _connectionString = "";
        _result = result;
    }

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private IResult<string> _result;

    public IAccessType AccessType { get { return new SqlServer(); } }
    public IPerson Instance { get; private set; }

    public IResult<string> Add(IPerson instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Get(IPerson instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Delete(IPerson instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Update(IPerson instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
}

public class FactoryDataAccess : IFactoryDataAccess
{
    internal FactoryDataAccess() { }

    public IDataAccessor<I, T> Create<I, T>()
    {
        var model = typeof(I);
        var target = typeof(T);

        if (model.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IPerson)))
        {
            if (target == typeof(SqlServer)) {

                var accessor = new Person.SQLDataAccessor(new Result());

                // This next line FAILS!
                return (IDataAccessorModel<I, T>)accessor;
            }
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("Type " + target.FullName + " and Source " + model.FullName + " is not supported.");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Please keep in mind that `IDataAccessorModel` can be used by any desired DataAccess type you wish to define.

Comment: How is `Person.SQLDataAccessor()` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me if I declare `SQLDataAccessor`  like this:

```
public class SQLDataAccessor : IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, SqlServer>
{
    ...
}
```

You are probably calling it like this

```
var factory = new FactoryDataAccess();
var da = factory.Create<IPerson, SqlServer>();
```

i.e. you call it with `T` being `SqlServer`. If you declare `T` as `IAccessType` in `SQLDataAccessor` it is not guaranteed that `IAccessType` would be `SqlServer`. Therefore the casting error. (However, `SqlServer` is guaranteed to be `IAccessType` as it probably implements it.)

Comment: Yes, I am indeed "trying" to call it as described above.  And...I can create the instance...it is the return that fails.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: `da` is really created and returned when I run the code. Derive `SQLDataAccessor` from `IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, SqlServer>` instead of `IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, IAccessType>`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH! I knew I was close.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLDataAccessor` implements `IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, IAccessType>`, so it would work only if `<I, T>` were `<IPerson, IAccessType>`. There is no guarantee about that, since the method is generic and I and T could be any type, so the cast fails.

Of course, since you're checking the types of I and T, you *know* the cast would be valid, but the compiler doesn't. You can trick it like this:

```
return (IDataAccessorModel<I, T>)(object)accessor;
```

However, since `T` *has* to be `SqlServer`, it doesn't make sense to make it a generic type parameter. And since `I` has to implement `IPerson`, there should be a constraint on it. So the method signature should be:

```
public IDataAccessor<I, T> Create<T>() where T : IPerson
```

Comment: I'm trying to make FactoryDataAccess "generically" return various instance of IDataAccessor.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLDataAccessor` is not a generic class, but implements `IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, IAccessType>` exactly, so your method `Create` should return `IDataAccessor<IPerson, IAccessType>`, but you probably called it with other generic types.

Change `SqlDataAccessor` to:

```
public class SQLDataAccessor<I, T> : IDataAccessorModel<I, T>
{
    internal SQLDataAccessor(IResult<string> result)
    {
        _connectionString = "";
        _result = result;
    }

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private IResult<string> _result;

    public T AccessType { get { return new SqlServer(); } }
    public I Instance { get; private set; }

    public IResult<string> Add(I instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Get(I instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Delete(I instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
    public IResult<string> Update(I instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
        return _result;
    }
}
```

You might want to limit `I` and `T` to the interfaces, so add a `where` constraint:

```
public class SQLDataAccessor<I, T> : IDataAccessorModel<I, T> 
    where I : IPerson
    where T : IAccessType
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, `I` could be any type derived from `IPerson` and `T` is exactly of type `SqlServer`, which would cause the cast to fail since `SQLDataAccessor` implements the `IDataAccessorModel` with different parameters. You would need to have a more exact cast, such as:

```
return (IDataAccessorModel<IPerson, IAccessType>)accessor;
```

Comment: 'Common.Contracts.DataAccessors.IDataAccessorModel<SampleLibrary.Contracts.Models.IPerson,Common.Contracts.DataAccessors.Types.IAccessType>' to 'Common.Contracts.DataAccessors.IDataAccessor<I,T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @PrisonerZERO, what's the point of making it generic if you only support specific types?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO you might have to add additional conditions to the type parameters as suggested in some of the other answers. Also, take a look at [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx); perhaps that is what you need to implement in your interface.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque SQLDataAccessor is supposed to be the concrete version of IDataAccessorModel as it relates to the Person (object). Thanks for the help